# JVMTI Invoke toString(); on an Java object from C++ code

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

So, I was trying to invoke the toString(); method on an object (in this case an enum). This immediately crashed my application. I am assuming that, since the toString(); method isn't declared directly in the enum but inherited from the Object class (Enum in this case) it is not able to find the method and therefore causes an error.

```cpp
bool is_miss() {
    // the enum I want to invoke toString() on, the type() method works just fine and returns the jobject 
    jobject rt_type = type(); 
    // I assume that this is where i'm doing something wrong
    // Edit: My assumption was right, this is the line that causes the crash
    jmethodID method = m_jenv->GetMethodID(m_jenv->GetObjectClass(rt_type), "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring str = (jstring)m_jenv->CallObjectMethod(rt_type, method);
    jboolean is_copy = jboolean{ true };
    return std::string(m_jenv->GetStringUTFChars(str, &is_copy));
}
```

How m_jenv is declared:

```cpp
JNIEnv* m_jenv;
```

And it's initialization:

```
// ... other code ...
jsize count;
if (JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(&m_jvm, 1, &count) != JNI_OK || count == 0) {
    return;
}

jint res = m_jvm->GetEnv((void**)&m_jenv, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
if (res == JNI_EDETACHED) {
    res = m_jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void**)&m_jenv, nullptr);
}

if (res != JNI_OK) {
    return;
}
// ... other code ...
```

However, the initialization works and the m_jenv field is accessed through a global variable holding a class that holds the JNIEnv* field. It's accessed by countless methods, even within the class of the is_miss() method and it's only this method causing an error.

How would I invoke the toString method on a enum (or Java object in general) via JVMTI?

Comment: Don't assume, verify with `m_jenv->ExceptionOccurred()` after every JNI call.

Comment: I've done some more investigation on the issue and tried checking for ExceptionOccured and invoking ExceptionDescribe() after 'jmethodID method = m_jenv->GetMethodID(m_jenv->....);' and it indeed is this line causing the crash. However, since this immediately crashes the application it doesn't even reach the ExceptionOccured() method call.

Comment: Then you need to tell us more about where `m_jenv` came from and its lifecycle.

Comment: JNIEnv* m_jenv; - this is how it is declared and I can tell it's properly initialized. It's used in many other functions and works just fine. It's a global variable and countless other methods access the exact same field, other methods within the same class the code i posted comes from work just fine aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been experimenting a bit, and now that I found a solution it makes sense why it didn't work.

Instead of trying to find the toString() method in the class directly, I passed the class found at the classpath of java/lang/Enum (or java/lang/Object for non-enum types) to the getMethodID() function.

```
jmethodID method = m_jenv->GetMethodID(m_jenv->FindClass("java/lang/Enum"), "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

And then just passed my jobject to CallObjectMethod().

```
jobject result = m_jenv->CallObjectMethod(rt_type, method);
```

Comment: weird. I had assumed the `GetObjectClass` call would just work